# Is there a generic way to tell if a username is valid on a Unix-like given system?

Tags: linux, ldap, solaris, user-management

I'm looking for a cross-platform way of determining whether or not a username and groupname is valid.  The platforms are Linux, Solaris, Aix, and HPUX.  It would need to work whether the user/group is defined locally (e.g. /etc/passwd) or through a service like LDAP or NIS/YP.  It's probably wishful thinking that such a method exists, but it can't hurt (too much) to ask.  Thanks!

Additional Info: Unfortunately I don't control the systems where this will run; the script is going out to clients and they can do whatever they want.  And I don't have a way to test any of this myself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does "getent passwd | grep " not get you anywhere ?

Comment: BTW, you do not need to grep, `getent passwd username` works.

Comment: Does getent hook into LDAP and NIS?

Comment: @Joe At least on Solaris, getent goes through the nsswitch backend to get the data from whatever you've configured in nsswitch.conf (NIS, LDAP, /etc/* files and so on).

Comment: Generally, getent will hook into NIS and LDAP.  getent should be calling the appropriate C library calls to pull user ID information.  As long as LDAP or NIS is setup correctly on a system, the getent command will return information about those entries.

Comment: @ptman, yea i know :( but, but, i love grep !

Answer (score 2):

From [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6822/verify-if-user-account-exists-in-linux-unix):

```
id <username>
```

Answer (score 1):

If not groking the flatfiles, I typically use the commands `id` or `finger`.  If you have the system configured to use LDAP or NIS/YP system-wide, any command-line utility should share this functionality.

Ultimately, for your solution to be infallible, you will likely have to write more complicated logic into your script.  This is a good example of why IT departments often try to prevent too many technology variances.